# TapGestureRecognizer is only on apart of view after view resize?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I added `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my `uitableviewcell` like

```
Mycell *outCell = (Mycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (!outCell) {
                outCell = [[Mycell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
                [outCell.bubbleView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }
```

outCell.bubbleView is added to contentview, outCell.bubbleView is resized according to image size is pass to Mycell.
When my app runs, `TapGestureRecognizer` is only fire when i tap on top of cell(where have height equal default cell height, other parth of cell is not)
Have any answers for my problem? Thanks in anvanced.

Comment: Try to Give any Background color to bubble view and try to tap on it then see, is your Tap selector fire or not.

Comment: call recognizer.tag=indexpath.row;

Comment: Tap selector only fire on top area which have height equal default height(I guess), other area is not

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
    Mycell *outCell = (Mycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!outCell)
    {
        outCell = [[Mycell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        UIView *tapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:outCell.bounds];
        tapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [tapView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [outCell addSubview:tapView];
    }
```

Comment: Problem not yet settled

Comment: Does not take tap anywhere or again only at the top??

Comment: Yes, only at the top, Thank you

Comment: Try changing the background color of the tapView and see if it covers the entire cell area or not.

Comment: could be auto resizing issue. im not sure. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Adithya. You're right, according to your suggestion, I set self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; in my MyCell class and my problem is solved. Thanks again